# Servicebus queue triggered azure function not able to consume messsage sent from .net framework nservicebus client

Tags: azure-functions, nservicebus

public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testqueue",, Connection = "queueConn")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{
try
{

///////////
message is not even hitting the function. however it is failing with the below error message.
///////
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ExportInspection. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'mySbMsg'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: The Message with ContentType 'null' failed to deserialize to a string with the message: 'Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'base64Binary', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.'. System.Private.DataContractSerialization: Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'base64Binary', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.

why is the content type null and how to resolve this issue

Comment: This could be an indication that 
1. Function is not activated
2. And may be it is not activated while a message is found on the queue 
3. Check your function configuration

Comment: Also for serialization error check this action Item https://i.imgur.com/DonRC6M.png

Comment: What's your incoming message looks like? Have you analyzed it? Who's sending the message? Is it sent by the same Service Bus SDK or not? Share those details as they matter. I have a strong feeling you're trying to process a legacy formatted message with a newer Functions SDK that is using the latest ASB SDK.                                                          
"message is not even hitting the function" - then this is not NServiceBus related. Please remove `nservicebus` tag.

Comment: SeanFeldman the message is sent from nservicebus v7 client.  below is the incoming message @base64Binary3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�'{"InspectionId":1289411387,"Type":1}

Comment: Try UTF8 encoding in the message